# Parallax image not appearing in google chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I tried [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ungmo2/pen/vXkrEj) in xampp and it's not working.

[image]

My html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="./Products/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /></link>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="image" data-type="background" data-speed="2"></div>
    <div class="stuff" data-type="content"><h1>Simple Parallax scroll</h1><h2>Reoptimized</h2></div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="image" data-type="background" data-speed="7"></div>
    <div class="stuff" data-type="content"><h2>Made to be fast</h2><p>Lorem Deserunt maiores minima ipsa. Adipisci, corrupti, voluptatibus! Similique quidem necessitatibus provident.</p></div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="image" data-type="background" data-speed="6"></div>
    <div class="stuff" data-type="content">Accusamus at ex amet perferendis atque fuga, ad earum, ipsa perspiciatis, dolore neque, accusantium consectetur quis voluptatibus culpa architecto animi natus facere expedita sed. Voluptatem odit explicabo amet neque aut.</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="image" data-type="background" data-speed="5"></div>
    <div class="stuff" data-type="content">Accusamus at ex amet perferendis atque fuga, ad earum, ipsa perspiciatis, dolore neque, accusantium consectetur quis voluptatibus culpa architecto animi natus facere expedita sed. Voluptatem odit explicabo amet neque aut.</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="image" data-type="background" data-speed="3"></div>
    <div class="stuff" data-type="content">Accusamus at ex amet perferendis atque fuga, ad earum, ipsa perspiciatis, dolore neque, accusantium consectetur quis voluptatibus culpa architecto animi natus facere expedita sed. Voluptatem odit explicabo amet neque aut.</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="image" data-type="background" data-speed="3"></div>
    <div class="stuff" data-type="content">Accusamus at ex amet perferendis atque fuga, ad earum, ipsa perspiciatis, dolore neque, accusantium consectetur quis voluptatibus culpa architecto animi natus facere expedita sed. Voluptatem odit explicabo amet neque aut.</div>
  </section>
</div>


<script src="./Products/js.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is option for exporting code zip file which works fine.

[image]